# Python: find a series of Chinese characters within a string and apply a function

Tags: python, regex

I've got a series of text that is mostly English, but contains some phrases with Chinese characters. Here's two examples:

```
s1 = "You say: 你好. I say: 再見"
s2 = "答案, my friend, 在風在吹"
```

I'm trying to find each block of Chinese, apply a function which will translate the text (I already have a way to do the translation), then replace the translated text in the string. So the output would be something like this:

```
o1 = "You say: hello. I say: goodbye"
o2 = "The answer, my friend, is blowing in the wind"
```

I can find the Chinese characters easily by doing this:

```
utf_line = s1.decode('utf-8') 
re.findall(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+',utf_line)
```

...But I end up with a list of all the Chinese characters and no way of determining where each phrase begins and ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always use a in-place replace of the matched regular expression by using    `re.sub()` in python.

Try this:

```
print(re.sub(r'([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)', translate('\g<0>'), utf_line))
```

Comment: I got this to work with a minor tweak, adding "ur": `print(re.sub(ur'([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)', translate('\g<0>'), utf_line))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave my answer in Python 3. In Python 3, 'ur'  and 'r' prefixes are considered synonyms. However, this is not the case in Python 2, which you seem to be using. But hey, you got the job done!

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the indexes using [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). You could use [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead, and refer to [m.group()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), [m.start()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) and [m.end()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end).

However, for your particular case, it seems more practical to call a function using [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string

**Code:**

```python
import re

s = "You say: 你好. I say: 再見. 答案, my friend, 在風在吹"
utf_line = s.decode('utf-8')

dict = {"你好" : "hello",
        "再見" : "goodbye",
        "答案" : "The answer",
        "在風在吹" : "is blowing in the wind",
       }

def translate(m):
    block = m.group().encode('utf-8')
    # Do your translation here

    # this is just an example
    if block in dict:
        return dict[ block ]
    else:
        return "{unknown}"


utf_translated = re.sub(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', translate, utf_line, re.UNICODE)

print utf_translated.encode('utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
You say: hello. I say: goodbye. The answer, my friend, is blowing in the wind
```

- [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/Dq1muC)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to capture everything, but in different capture groups, so you can differentiate later if they're in Chinese or not.

```
ret = re.findall(ur'([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)|([^\u4e00-\u9fff]+)', utf_line)
result = []
for match in ret:
    if match[0]:
        result.append(translate(match[0]))
    else:
        result.append(match[1])

print(''.join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression `Match` objects give you the start and end indexes of a match. So, instead of `findall`, do your own search and record the indexes as you go. Then, you can translate each extent and replace in the string based on the known indexes of the phrases.

```
import re

_scan_chinese_re = re.compile(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+')

s1 = "You say: 你好. I say: 再見"
s2 = "答案, my friend, 在風在吹"

def translator(chinese_text):
    """My no good translator"""
    return ' '.join('??' for _ in chinese_text)

def scanner(text):
    """Scan text string, translate chinese and return copy"""
    print('----> text:', text)

    # list of extents where chinese text is found
    chinese_inserts = [] # [start, end]

    # keep scanning text to end
    index = 0
    while index < len(text):
        m = _scan_chinese_re.search(text[index:])
        if not m:
            break
        # get extent from match object and add to list
        start = index + m.start()
        end = index + m.end()
        print('chinese at index', start, text[start:end])
        chinese_inserts.append([start, end])
        index += end

    # copy string and replace backwards so we don't mess up indexes
    copy = list(text)
    while chinese_inserts:
        start, end = chinese_inserts.pop()
        copy[start:end] = translator(text[start:end])
    text = ''.join(copy)
    print('final', text)
    return text

scanner(s1)
scanner(s2)
```

With my questionable translator, the result is

```
----> text: You say: 你好. I say: 再見
chinese at index 9 你好
chinese at index 20 再見
final You say: ?? ??. I say: ?? ??
----> text: 答案, my friend, 在風在吹
chinese at index 0 答案
chinese at index 15 在風在吹
final ?? ??, my friend, ?? ?? ?? ??
```