# why can not match chinese characters by using ”regex“ at python ？

Tags: python, regex

```py
 import re
 html="""<div class="tB-mb">
                   <span class="t-d">0</span> 
                   <span class="t-d">0</span> 天 
                   <span class="t-h">0</span>
                   <span class="t-h">0</span> 时
                   <span class="t-m">0</span>
                   <span class="t-m">0</span> 分 
                   <span class="t-s">0</span>
                   <span class="t-s">0</span> 秒
     """
 tmp=re.compile(u"(<div class='tB-mb'>).*?([\u4e00-\u9fa5]).*?",re.U)
 result=re.findall(tmp,html.decode("utf-8"))
 print result
 []
```

As mentioned above why my code can not match  Chinese characters？

Comment: hi @Stephen2017, don't forget to use PEP8 coding style to format your code. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122058/python-find-a-series-of-chinese-characters-within-a-string-and-apply-a-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: find a series of Chinese characters within a string and apply a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122058/python-find-a-series-of-chinese-characters-within-a-string-and-apply-a-function)

Comment: your problem is not exactly the chinese characters I guess... you can't extract all chinese character inside the div by the pattern you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuu're using single quotes in `<div class='tB-mb'>` for your regex pattern whereas `html` has `div`'s `class` in double quotes. I think there's a simpler pattern which can extract what you want:

```
tmp = re.compile(u"(?m)([\u4e00-\u9fa5])+", re.U)
result=re.findall(tmp,html)
print result
```

Output:
`['天', '时', '分', '秒']`

If your `html` is bigger than what is shown in the question, and you want only the Chinese characters in `<div class="tB-mb">`, you can first extract the text within the `div` and then search inside that text:

```
inside_text = re.search(r'<div class="tB-mb">[\s\S]+</div>', html).group()
result = re.findall(tmp,inside_text)
```

Output will be as desired.